# Query to display the department names manager department name

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have to write a query to display Worker Department and its Manager Department from a table.

A Department cannot manage itself and all the departments should be displayed once with its Manager department.

This is the schema of the  Employee and  Department tables:

```
Employees:

empno char[6]

firstname varchar[12]

lastname varchar[15]

workdept char[3]

job char[9]
```

```
Department:

deptno char[3]

deptname varchar[36]

mgrno char[6]

admrdept char [3]

location char[16]
```

Am I missing something because I cant seem to do it.

This is the output I am expecting (Worker dept. and Manager Dept. are aliases):

```
Worker Dept.                            Manager Dept.
Administration Systems                  Development Center
Development Center                      Spiffy Computer Service
Information Center                      Spiffy Computer Service
Manufacturing Systems                   Development Center
Planning                                Spiffy Computer Service Div
Support Services                        Spiffy Computer Service Div
```

I have tried this but I cant get the manager Dept.:

```
SELECT distinct d.deptname,  d.location , d.admrdept  
FROM Department d 
JOIN Employee e on d.deptno = workdept
```

PS: I am getting the 3rd column as the dept. code according to the above query, how do I make the connection to the dept name.

Comment: Please do not post images of your table schema, post it in text.  Also what have you tried?

Comment: Could you post the query you have tried and the output that you are expecting as a text (not an image)?

Comment: @RakhiAgrawal added the details.

Comment: Is the mgrno the same as empno?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell based on the information given but I think you want:

```
select d.deptname as WorkerDept, md.deptname as ManagerDept
from Employee e
inner join Department d
   on (e.workdept = d.deptno)
inner join Department md
   on (d.admrdept = md.deptno)
where d.deptno != md.deptno
```

Comment: This is great . Just one issue , it is showing one of the dept which manages itself.